# Carrying on data from a UITableView cell to another VC's tableview? (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift

I'm currently working on a project in swift where I have created a ViewController which has a UITableView.

http://prntscr.com/5wft7u

This UITableView you can swipe to delete. I'm wanting to make a 'Deleted items' or 'Recycle bin' section kind of thing on my other view where once the delete button is pressed it deletes from the first tableView and is now inserted into the 'Deleted items' view tableview cell.

*Edit:

I've been thinking, I would make another array for the recycled items. In the UITableViewRowAction handler for deleting items, once you remove something out of your projects array, you add it to your recycled array. Then pass that recycled array over to the other VC in prepareForSegue method, and the other VC will load that array into the table.

I cant get this too work.. can someone please show me the code?

First view code: pastebin.com/dBucJ9w0 
View: prntscr.com/5wft7u

The second view code is just a default VC class.
The view for the second class is only a TableView.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add another array to each of your ViewControllers. 
First VC:
Add var `deleted: [String] = []` after your `projects` declaration. Then do this:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    if editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyle.Delete {
        deleted.append(projects[indexPath.row])
        projects.removeAtIndex(indexPath.row)
        tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Automatic)
    }
}
```

Finally make a prepareForSegue function to pass the data:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "YourIdentifier" {
        let destination = segue.destinationViewController as YourSecondViewControllerClass
        destination.arrayThatYouAdded = deleted
   }
}
```

And then just display the `arrayThatYouAdded` property in your second view controller however you would like in a table view.

Comment: Hey i've been messing around with the code and have done what you said. I was wondering, in my first VC, i have a handler that changes view and adds a UITableRowAction. One of these are 'Delete' so I dont think the first function (commitEditingstyle) isnt necessary? Do i have to add it in my handler or just keep it how it is. If i keep it how it is, it's still not adding it to the table.. so thats why it makes me think that. Cheers

Comment: ah i see now that you are manually adding the delete button in? If so, you wouldn't really need to override commitEditingStyle, you could just implement the deletion code in the handler for the delete button. However, that is kind of a funky way to implement deletion, but it should work I think.

Comment: So how could I implement the deletion code in the handler? I don't exactly get what you're saying?

Comment: Oh yeah, you mean add **deleted.append(projects[indexPath.row])** to the deletion action row part, i've tried that but it keeps prompting me to include **self.deleted.append(self.projects[indexPath.row])** and when i run it it says array is out of range. Where would I put it in the code? ^^ is after the - **self.tableView.dataSource?.tableView?(self.tableView, commitEditingStyle: .Delete, forRowAtIndexPath: indexPath)** - but above '**return**'

Comment: Unless it's my fourthVC screwing up                                                 | FourthVC - http://pastebin.com/PME6YGcD

Comment: you definitely need the self in a closure. As for why that would be out of range, I am not really sure. What I meant though is that you could possibly implement what you currently have in commitEditingStyle in the closure and not call commitEditingStyle, making all the deletion code in that one handler. I really don't know if this would work though. The only table deletion that is similar to your method that I have actually implemented is what I posted above.

Comment: If i don't call commitEditingStyle the delete/edit cell actions don't even show when I swipe.. I definitely need the function commitEditingStyle but the thing is what I have inside that function and what i have inside the deleteRowAction function.

Comment: I tried doing http://prntscr.com/5xkl9c and it turns out, i can swipe but when I click delete nothing happens. This is confusing me.. I can't find anything on the internet ^_^